# Why $this->request->getParam('_csrfToken') is returning false instead of a CSRF token in CakePHP 3 application

Tags: javascript, csrf, csrf-token, cakephp-3.4

This piece of code $this->request->getParam('_csrfToken') is generating CSRF token in my production application and not in local and test server. Something is wrong and not working in my local app.